# Running repetitive task through Bash script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, scripting

I'm running a few repetitive tasks and I think will be good to create a small bash script to perform all them in just one command: run the bash script. This are the tasks I need to run:

```
# stop HTTPD, clear logs, start HTTPD back
service httpd stop
cd /var/log/httpd/
rm -r *
service httpd start

# clear PHP error logs
truncate /var/log/php/php_errors.log --size 0

# clear MySQL error, query and slow logs
truncate /var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log --size 0
truncate /var/log/mysql/mysql_query.log --size 0
truncate /var/log/mysql/mysql_slow.log --size 0
```

So this is how I am doing:

```
#! /bin/bash

# stop HTTPD, clear logs, start HTTPD back
service httpd stop
cd /var/log/httpd/
rm -r *
service httpd start

# clear PHP error logs
truncate /var/log/php/php_errors.log --size 0

# clear MySQL error, query and slow logs
truncate /var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log --size 0
truncate /var/log/mysql/mysql_query.log --size 0
truncate /var/log/mysql/mysql_slow.log --size 0
```

But I am getting this error all the time and I don't know what I am doing wrong:

> bash: ./cleanup.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

What I am doing wrong and/or missing?

Comment: Additionally to the `^M` problem pointed in the answer, delete space after `!` in shebang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run [`dos2unix`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) on your file, which is presumably copied into your Linux distribution with Windows file endings. The `^M`, aka the [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return#Computers) character, trips your Linux distribution into thinking it needs to look for a command `bash^M`, instead of `bash`.

To actually view the `^M` characters, you can open your file with `cat -A`:

```
$ cat -A file
# --- comment: expected output below ---
#! /bin/bash^M
# stop HTTPD, clear logs, start HTTPD back^M
service httpd stop^M
cd /var/log/httpd/^M
```

In case you do not have `dos2unix` installed, you can also try replacing using the `tr` command (as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Conversion_utilities)):

```
tr -d '\r' < inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: Thx that fixes the issue on the script and point me on the right direction to configure my IDE to avoid the windows file endings